# Translate formula boolean to variables expression

Tags: boolean-computation

I need prepare simple parser for Boolean formula in format CNF:

So we have some formula like: 
$$ 
F = (x_1  \lor x_2)  \land (x_1 \lor \overline x_3) \land (x_2 \lor x_4) \land (\overline x_3 \lor \overline x_4) \land (\overline x_1 \lor \overline x_4)
$$

and mapping:

$  (x \lor y) = (1-x-y+xy), (x \lor \overline y) = (y-xy),  (\overline x \lor y) = (x - xy), (\overline x \lor \overline y) = (xy)$

```
(x1 || x2) && (x3 || !x2) && (x2 || x4) && (!x3 || !x4) && (!x1 || !x4)
```

For example:

```
 y = 3 + x1 - 2 * x4 + 2 x3 * x4 + x2*(-x3 + x4)
```

We have simple answer in Mathematica 12?

Comment: What is the mapping for &&?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can use [`BooleanConvert`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BooleanConvert) to convert to a [`Nand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nand) + [`Not`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Not) expression, and then replace [`Not`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Not) with `(1-#)&` and [`Nand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nand) with [`Times`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Times)?

```
toVariables[bool_] := ReplaceAll[
    BooleanConvert[bool, "Nand"],
    {Not->Function[1-#], Nand->Times}
]
```

For example:

```
Expand @* toVariables /@ {x || y, x || !y, !x || y, !x || !y}
```

> {1 - x - y + x y, y - x y, x - x y, x y}

as requested. For your more complicated example:

```
toVariables[(x1 || x2) && (x3 || !x2) && (x2 || x4) && (!x3 || !x4) && (!x1 || !x4)]
```

> 1 - x2 x3 (1 - x4)

This doesn't agree with your requested output, so probably converting to [`Nand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nand) is not appropriate for expressions involving [`And`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/And).